# What is 猫舅 in the following sentence?

Tags: culture, meaning

I assume this is a cultural thing that I am not aware of, but a friend just updated their status to say:

> 希望猫舅变成天使守护全家

*Xīwàng māo jiù biàn chéng tiānshǐ shǒuhù quán jiā*

Who or what is 猫舅?

Comment: Can you provide more info on the context? In my answer, I just guess what it means, and I need the context to give a better answer.

Comment: I've never heard of it. I think you'd better ask himself. It may be a nickname of somebody. It may be a character in some cartoon/TV/novel. It may be ...

Comment: If it's a status, I think it might be a typo or a nickname for the speaker's partner.

Comment: I assume his cat was dead, can you confirm this?

Answer (score 3):

猫舅 in this sentence just means cat. It's become slang to say 猫舅 when one just means cat.

Also the following might be helpful too:

- 猪爹 (pig dad) - means pig
- 猫舅 (cat uncle) - cat
- 狗老爷 (dog grandpa) - dog

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I came across these three a few times when I was searching for an answer myself. Is there any information on the origin of these three?

Comment: i searched a while online and couldn't find the origin...i wonder if it has to do w/ reincarnation, like a reminder to treating animals well bcz they might be your relatives from past lives. i'll ask my friends in china when i call them. if i get any more info i'll post an update.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is:

Your friend might have some dogs, cats and other animals as pets. He might want to regard all these pets as a big family, to each member of which he might want to give a lovely nickname. For example, he might have:

> 猫舅， 猫姨， 狗外甥， 兔大姑

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the word "猫舅". 
舅舅 is used to refers to a brother of your mother. If one's mother is A, and she has two brothers: B and C,
he would call B or C "舅舅"

So I guess 猫舅 is used to call a brother of the cat's mother. In your example, you friend uses this word from a cat's view.